# How to get multi-row sort/filtering headers in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have a spreadsheet which uses 2 rows for header information.  Filtering by selecting a column is implicitly assuming only 1 row of header information.  Sorting has a header row checkbox but that only toggles treating the first row as a header.

Is there a way to make Excel treat the first two rows as headers?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No.  Omit the first row from your range when you auto filter.  This way the auto filter buttons  appear only on your bottom header row and the data gets filtered.  I expect that right now your second header row is getting pulled into your 'data'.

You can't select a single cell and have excel figure this out.  You have to select the range of cells you want excel to include.

Comment: It is.  I didn't realize I could select a specific cell to start the filtering at, as opposed to doing a column select.

Comment: I would write: "Yes, Omit the first row ..." etc

Answer (score 8):

An easy way to accomplish the sort function using multiple header rows is to insert a blank row just above the row you want to sort by *(ideally, it is bottom-most in your header. If not, make it so.)*. Then click on the 'row' number highlighting the empty row. Right click that row and select "Hide'. The new, empty row will vanish leaving your header the way you wanted it to look and Excel will interpret your category row as the header.

Answer (score 4):

If you select an entire row (by selecting the row number to the left of the row) and then enable your filter (Data > Filter) then it will give you filters for everything below the selected row and ignore everything above it.

Comment: This is the correct answer and the easiest. This works in excel 2016 since this is a much older question.

Comment: Thank you!  Why is everyone else on here doing it so complicated?

Comment: @user291695: I'm guessing from the date on OP that that's how it was probably done for an older version of MS Office as in older answers and the newer answers just don't make sense. Don't know for sure though.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the following works in Excel 2010, even after saving the file back as an Excel 2007 and re-opening (so presumably works in Excel 2007 as well...)

Assuming a 3 row header. Set the spreadsheet filter range to Start at cell $A$4 and ensure that it covers the full extent of data you want to sort. SAVE THE FILE.

Henceforth, any sort will treat rows 1 to 3 as headers and therefore sort from row 4 onwards only. - UNLESS you change or cancel the filter range....

Comment: The response from deedgess worked for me. When you add a filter, excel assumes every row above it is a header. In my case, I have a 2 row header. I selected row 2 and turned on the filter. Then I selected custom sort and checked the box for header. When the sort happened, both row 1 and row 2 remained as header.

Comment: Interesting, when I do it in Excel 1911 sorting with the filter's dropdown works, but Custom Sort doesn't: row 2 stayed put, but row 1 got sorted together with everything else. So the "lowest" value from my actual data is now in row 1, and the original row 1 is stuck within my data range.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to make Excel treat the first two rows as headers?

**Yes there is, *if* you can make *one small change* to the first header column.**

If you are able to merge cells `A1` and `A2` using "Merge & Center", then Excel will properly identify both rows as header rows.

For example:

[image: Sample spreadsheet data with multiple header rows]

Doing an auto-sort on this will automatically (and improperly) select the second row:

[image: Improper Auto-sort Selection]

But now merge `A1` and `A2` together:

[image: Merged Top Right Cells]

...and Excel will now properly ignore both header rows when auto-selecting the sort area:

[image: Proper Auto-sort Selection]

### Exceptions:

This obviously won't work if your first column requires both lines for headers, unless you're willing to live with one merged cell with two separate lines of text. While this will *look* fine, it's isn't semantically correct and could lead to problems in extreme edge cases if one assumes they are separate lines.

This also won't work if `A1` is merged horizontally with `B1`, etc. There is no way around this problem unless you add a dummy column as the first column. If you can't do that, you will have to manually select all the data prior to sorting.

---

Note: all phone numbers were randomly generated with the formula below. Any similarity to an existing and valid number is purely coincidence.

`=REPLACE(REPLACE(RANDBETWEEN(1000000000,9999999999),4,0,"-"),8,0,"-")`

Comment: This is a great answer and it should have been upvoted by more people.

Answer (score 1):

To filter a list with 2 header rows, where the second row contains the column headings, here is what I did.

- Cut the first row
- Turn filtering off
- Turn filtering on again so that the second row is filtered. This tells Excel which is the row with the column headings.
- Paste the first row back in again above the row with the filters and column headings
- Check to see if the filter now works, with the column headings on the second row.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm on SuperUser and not on StackOverflow, but the solution to this problem can be found in using VBA code on Excel 2016.

I have similar (more complex) problem.

I want to add some filters on explicit columns but not on row 1 only on row 2 as you can see in following screen's capture.

[image]

I have tried using Excel GUI but this seems impossible, so I have written following code:

```
'********************************************************
'* SetFilter()
'********************************************************
'* PUBLIC method to call to define CUSTOM AutoFilter
'* on complex header.
'********************************************************

Sub SetFilter()
  'Compute last row number
  Dim nLast As Long
  nLast = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  'Lock screen update 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'Unmerge merged cells to allow adding filter
  Range("A1:A2").MergeCells = False
  Range("B1:B2").MergeCells = False
  Range("C1:C2").MergeCells = False
  Range("D1:D2").MergeCells = False
  Range("E1:E2").MergeCells = False
  Range("F1:F2").MergeCells = False

  'Add filter on row 2 and not 1  
  Range("A2:Z" & nLast).Select
  Selection.AutoFilter

  'Remove (or Hide) filter combobox for some columns
  Selection.AutoFilter Field:=GetColumnIndex("C"), VisibleDropDown:=False
  Selection.AutoFilter Field:=GetColumnIndex("G"), VisibleDropDown:=False
  Selection.AutoFilter Field:=GetColumnIndex("H"), VisibleDropDown:=False

  'Merge unmerged cells to restore previous state
  Range("A1:A2").MergeCells = True
  Range("B1:B2").MergeCells = True
  Range("C1:C2").MergeCells = True
  Range("D1:D2").MergeCells = True
  Range("E1:E2").MergeCells = True
  Range("F1:F2").MergeCells = True

  'Unlock screen update 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

'********************************************************
'* GetColumnIndex()
'********************************************************
'* return column's index from column letters
'********************************************************

Function GetColumnIndex(sColLetter As String) As Integer
    Dim n As Integer: n = 0
    Dim iMax As Integer: iMax = Len(sColLetter)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sChar As String
    Dim c As Integer

    For i = 1 To iMax
        sChar = Mid(sColLetter, i, 1)
        c = 1 + Asc(sChar) - Asc("A")
        n = n * 26 + c
    Next

    If n = 1 Then
      n = 1
    End If

    GetColumnIndex = n
End Function
```

The logic of this code is

A. Unmerge vertically merged header cells to allow adding filter on row
    2

```
Range("A1:A2").MergeCells = False
```

Cells A1 and A2 are unmerged.

B. Add AutoFilter on all cells of row 2

```
Range("A2:Z" & nLast).AutoFilter
```

AutoFilter is generated for cells in all rows except row 1.

C. Remove or hide FILTER Combobox for some columns

```
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=GetColumnIndex("C"), VisibleDropDown:=False
```

DropBox of Column "C" is hidden.

D. Merge unmerged cells to restore original state

```
Range("A1:A2").MergeCells = True
```

Cells A1 and A2 are merged again.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2007 indeed has the ability to automatically detect multi-row headers and will treat the first row as a header while sorting or filtering. To utilize this feature, simply position the cursor right below the header before making your first sort. By doing this, Excel will recognize the first row as a header and will not include it in the sorting or filtering process, treating the second row as the actual header.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. It's true that Excel 07 can autodetect multi-row headers in *some* cases, but it's based on cell contents, not on which cell you click. For example, if the first two rows are text and everything below is numeric, then Excel will assume the first 2 rows are both headers.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the cells that need to be sorted (all except the headers) and then select filter.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Excel 2010. To retain the heading rows (e.g. the first 4 rows), highlight row 5 and then turn on the filters. Rows 1 - 4 are excluded from the filter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so everyone's contribution led me to the way the works for me (so far).

1. ADD a blank row below your Multi-row(s) Header (if your header is 5 rows of info and/or odd cell sizes, then your NEW blank row will be Row6).
2. Click on Row6 (to the far left/ actually click the "6" (Excel Row #) to select the entire row / to infinity). BE sure NOT to click any other CELL, until you have completed #3 and #4 below, or you will 'Deselect' the row.  You want to keep it 'Selected'.
3. Go to the VIEW tab> Freeze Panes >Unfreeze (do this first to clear it) >Freeze.  This will freeze your 5 row header & also the blank row (row6).
4. Hold Down "ALT", then press the following keys: D, F, F (this is the shortcut to turnON & turnOff/clear all filters on the sheet.
5. From this point forward, whenever you return to use this sheet & you need those Filters on (if you previously turned them off for any reason), then >Select your Blank Row (as explained in #2); >TurnON all your filters (as explained in #4).

Sorry to be so wordy, but after you do it a few times, will likely love it (if you use Filters a lot).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1
Highlight the bottom header row. and then You can select just the cells in a row, or select the entire row.

Step 2
next click on  "Sort & Filter" on the Home tab, then you can select "Filter." Excel adds filter arrows to all the column names.

Step 3
then click an arrow and later select a sorting option to sort the entire table by that column.

Step 4
finally click on "Sort & Filter" and select "Filter" again if you want to get rid of the arrows, but keep the sorting area defined by the filter. now you can sort normally, Excel ignores the extra header rows

Answer (score -1):

Another way to accomplish in some cases is to enter a value in the second column that will cause the filter to include it, then make the text of that cell match the background colour of the cell.  Not that pretty since the header (row 1) will not be horizontally centred in the cell but it will work...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and found a solution that works for me.
For every row in the header that you don't want to see, you make te letters white (or the backgroundcolor).
When you sort you don't see all the same headers in the rows. To bad when you want to change something, but in that case you can also make them light grey.