# How do I create a table with multiple header rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How can I create a table in Excel that has two or more headers rows.  I want to keep the range as a table so I can use the built in tools such as re-sizing, totaling, formatting, etc...

I saw a table like this in another workbook, so I know it is possible.  However, I cannot find a reference on how to make a table with more than one header.  Does anyone know how to do this in Office 2010?  I would like to know how to do this even if it is only possible in VBA.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-row headers and excel 2007 sort/filtering](http://superuser.com/questions/62758/multi-row-headers-and-excel-2007-sort-filtering)

Comment: This is not a duplicate because the question is about the table feature in Excel and not about sorting/filtering a range.

Comment: The solution is the same though, only include the bottom row headers in your table range. This requires the bottom row headers to be unique, and there's no way around that using tables or filters. The column name has to be unique so you can reference them by name in formulas.