# How to make all merged cells the same size?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I `Ctrl`+`A` [this HTML](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1350694/000156761920003264/xslForm13F_X01/form13fInfoTable.xml) for [Bridgewater Associates, LP](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1350694/000156761920003264/0001567619-20-003264-index.htm) if you prefer XML. Then I copied and pasted to Excel. I need to see this table sorted in decreasing order of Column 5 SHRS OR PRN AMT (see red arrow), and clicked the arrow under the red arrow. Then an error message popped up.

[image]

Unquestionably the table is too long for me to spot and size each merged cell, and it's too unproductive for me to do this every 4 months for every new quarterly F13F.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is sorting in a table with a multiple-line header. This is not possible in this format (see [How to get multi-row sort/filtering headers in excel](https://superuser.com/questions/62758/how-to-get-multi-row-sort-filtering-headers-in-excel)), but what you can do is to leave out the first two rows of the table when you apply the Sort & Filter settings.

In your case, select the table **starting from line 13** and use Sort & Filter only on that part. With this, you can order by any column.

Answer (score 1):

Open up a fresh new Excel document and go to Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > From Web.  Paste the URL of that page in the next dialogue prompt's URL text field and press OK.  When the next window prompt loads, select Table 2 [image: Screenshot] then press Load.

Excel should now populate the table with the multi-line headers split out (with `null` values for the ones that were causing the problem).  Copy and paste-as-value to a separate sheet/workbook for a static copy.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me.
So I saved the excel as a CSV, edited it in Notepad++, and read it back into Excel so I could sort it there. Then I pasted it into MS Word in the "Merge Table" special option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me either.
I attempted to leave out the first two rows of the table when applying the Sort & Filter settings and that didn’t work…
So what I did was inserted 2 new blank rows above the cells I was trying to sort… and THIS DID WORK!!